# Ubuntu: errors in terminal: how to show them in english language?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, language

i installed Ubuntu in italian language. Now I would like to see the error commands in english.

For example if i write:

> $ mmmm

This is showed:

> mmmm: comando non trovato

I would like that

> mmmmm: command was not found

is showed.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: To get the error messages in English, install the English version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The language used by most applications uses the `LC_LANG` or `LANG` environment variables to find your language.

You can override it by adding a line

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

- to the file `~/.profile` if you want it to be changed for all applications (including GUI applications)
- to the file `~/.bashrc` for only applications you launch from inside the terminal (assuming your shell is `bash`).

You can also override it on a per-application basis by prefixing your command with that definition, e.g.

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls
```

Comment: Or you can set it for just the current session by entering `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

not always working.
you may have locale lang set in LANG variable overridden by LANGUAGE variable
should use then 
LANGUAGE=en_US:en 
in the end of  ~/.bashrc