# Terminal error messages are not in English

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, language

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed on my machine. Currently terminal error messages are not in English (actually they are in Russian).

For example,

```
$ mmmm
mmmm: команда не найдена
```

I want to see

```
$ mmmm
mmmmm: command was not found
```

Solution provided for [this SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/235764/ubuntu-errors-in-terminal-how-to-show-them-in-english-language) does not work for me.

Comment: did you tryed to reconfigure locales?

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: Try in terminal: export LANG=C and check again the system messages

Comment: @RomeoNinov after running your command I see the following on the screen: `\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430 'mmmm' \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0430`

Comment: @FranciscoTapia there is no effect...

Comment: try 
export LC_ALL=C

Comment: It's an SU post, not SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SO Post](https://superuser.com/questions/235764/ubuntu-errors-in-terminal-how-to-show-them-in-english-language) was in the right direction, but there are several environment variables which can be tested by an application.  I use this script for example to reliably set the locale for commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: with-locale,v 1.6 2011/10/27 22:51:45 tom Exp $
unset LANG
unset LC_ALL
unset LC_CTYPE
unset LESSCHARSET
unset LANGUAGE

LANG=$1
LC_ALL=$1
GDM_LANG=$1

export LANG
export LC_ALL
export GDM_LANG
shift
exec "$@"
```

That is, having `with-locale` in my path, I might do

```
with-locale C mmmmmm
```

to verify that it has no hardcoded messages.

You can *always* check to see what variables apply to your environment by running the [`locale`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) command.

One of the comments asked about `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.  That is,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

would provide you with the way to alter the *default* locale settings on the machine (see for example *[How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)* on AskUbuntu).  Your shell initialization could of course override those.  Note that because there are several variables, they can be set inconsistently.  The [locale(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/locale) manual page mentions a few of the possibilities, including the [`LANGUAGE`](https://superuser.com/questions/392439/lang-and-language-environment-variable-in-debian-based-systems) variable which can be the source of problems because it *overrides* the POSIX standard variables.

Comment: In my case the language was set through the `LANGUAGE` variable: `export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"`.  The changing of other variables did not change terminal language.